# Sort string into alphabetical order

Tags: php, string, sorting, implode

I'm working through the challenges on coderbyte.com to brush up on programming skills. The challenge is to sort a string `$str` into alphabetical order. The output must be a string, I'm 99% my logic and code is correct but its throwing errors,  Can anyone spot if I have done anything wrong before I contact coderbyte.

eg if $str = cat hat;
$imp should return 'aacht'
my code is:

```
function AlphabetSoup($str) {  


 $arr = str_split($str, 1);
 $sorted = sort($arr);
 $imp = implode('', $sorted);


  return $imp;  

}
```

Comment: also add a string and expected result?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

**sort() :- Returns TRUE on success or FALSE on failure.**
You need to quoting over string like `$str = 'cat hat';` and you will get result
Try

```
$str = 'cat hat';
$sparts = str_split($str);
sort($sparts);
$imp = implode('', $sparts); //aachtt 
return $imp;  // will be a string
```

Comment: I did, the add some code at the bottom for testing to see if you pass.. they trow a series of test cases in and the error code is showing that their line of code is not working now... so its them... not your code.

Comment: I'm solving all their question for interview i'm having and all sort function are not working even usort

Answer (score 1):

[**sort()**](http://php.net/manual/en/function.sort.php) returns true or false, not an array. Try this:

```
...
$arr = str_split($str, 1);
sort($arr);
$imp = implode('', $arr);
...
```

[**See demo**](http://3v4l.org/GIUSZ)

Comment: so there is no function like sort() that will return either a string or an array?

Comment: @ShoutItWebSolutions `sort()` sorts the given array. In your case, why would you need to create another array, when you can just use `sort` to sort the one you have? If you wanted, you could create a copy of the array and then sort that... `$arr2 = $arr; sort($arr2); ...` but why would you need to...?

Comment: @ShoutItWebSolutions try this solution most likely this will work just fine, `sort()` works on arrays, `str_split` just turned your input string into an array so that `sort()` could manage to sort it alphabetically. the `implode()` just glued up the sorted array back into a string again.

Comment: that was my logic... except I misunderstood the output of sort() i though it returned an array.

Answer (score 0):

`sort()` returns TRUE on success or FALSE on failure. so `$sorted` would contain `boolean` value not  an `array`.It will sort the array. try with -

```
$arr = str_split($str, 1);
sort($arr);
$imp = implode('', $arr);
```